# Why is my move_uploaded_file() not working

Tags: php

I am working locally on localhost and the site is D/xampp/htdocs/websites/site.com
I am also using this line of code to change .php extensions to just a / (fowardslash).

From the page which is located at site.com/admin/addevent/ i am trying to move the uploaded file which is an image to site.com/images/uploads. I am using MySQLi and my PHP code to do this is:

```
$target = "../images/uploads/";
$target = $target . $_FILES['image']['name'];
$pname = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ptemp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$ptype = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$psize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
if(move_uploaded_file($pname, $target)){
    echo "file moved";
}else{
    echo "not moved ";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might want to change this line to use the location of the temporary file (this is the location of the actual file to be moved). You are using what it found the name of the original file, which doesn't exist.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($pname, $target)){
```

Like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){
```

Or like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($ptemp, $target)){
```

Comment: Thanks, dont know where I got mixed up along the way. Long Day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use files temporary name. Try this:

```
    $target = "../images/uploads/";
$target = $target . $_FILES['image']['name'];
$pname = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ptemp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$ptype = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$psize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
if(move_uploaded_file($ptemp, $target)){
    echo "file moved";
}else{
    echo "not moved ";
}
```